# Jquery selector on data

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following html object, I want to select it based on the data-value

```
[<span class="selecter-item selected" data-value="CS 245">CS 245</span>]
```

I tried something like this, but it does not work.

```
$("span[data-value='CS 245']")
```

Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: Did you say object? As it is you selector is targeting the DOM, not some object.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the selector, except for the empty space at the end, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You have a `space` after 245
2. When I copied and pasted your HTML there was a character, `​` I had to delete after `=`.

**This clearly shows you may want to cleanup your HTML to avoid such issues.**

The demo works fine.

```js
alert( $("span[data-value='CS 245 ']").length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class=​"selecter-item selected" data-value="CS 245 ">​CS 245​</span>​
```

Comment: sorry yeah, I was not expecting that you copy over my code and test it. Its my bad. I will edit my question right now.

Comment: And why do you have square brackets around your markup? What object are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the value of data-value:

```
$("span").attr("data-value");
```

If you want to set the data_value, as shaN said:

```
$("span").attr("data-value","CS 245");
```

But if you want to select as you did try to delete the empty space data-value=​"CS 245 "

Answer (score 0):

You have `data-value=​"CS 245 "` **(Note the empty space!)** you should have then :

```
$("span[data-value='CS 245 ']")
```

Or just remove the empty space :) and should work the way you currently have it